# The view 'Details' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting errors when trying to return a the view `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Users", new { id = UserSearch.Id }, null)`  on my mvc 5 website.

I keep on recieving the error  `

```
The view 'Details' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Users/Details.aspx
~/Views/Users/Details.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Details.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Details.ascx
~/Views/Users/Details.cshtml
~/Views/Users/Details.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Details.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Details.vbhtml`
```

However similar action links work perfectly fine in my website.

Any help would be greatful.

Users controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Find(Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

Details page

```
@model BiteWebsite.Models.ApplicationUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


<div>
    <h4>Meal</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.County)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

**Updated
User Model**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string DateofBirth { get; set; }
        public virtual UserCuisineChoice UserCuisineChoice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the model?

Comment: I have added the user model

Comment: What file path is your details page in and what is it's name?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the the details page was in the wrong folder which was causing the error. Thanks for your help